# Number of real solutions of the equation $1+8^x+27^x = 2^x+12^x+9^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

> Find the number of real solutions $x\in\mathbb{R}$ of the equation
>   $$
> 1+8^x+27^x = 2^x+12^x+9^x
> $$

**My Attempt:**

Let $2^x=a>0$ and $3^x=b>0$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$. This allows us to change the equation to

$$
1+a^3+b^3 = a+a^2b+b^2
$$

This can be rewritten as

$$
(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)+1 = a+ab(a+b)
$$

How can I solve the problem from this point?

Comment: $x=0$ is a solution, and numerics suggests it is the only one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: by rearrangement inequality

$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$$

happens iff $a=b=c$.

Comment: How do we show equality is attained only if $a = b = c$? (The if direction is of course obvious.)

Comment: @SimonS  A simple way to check that is WLOG $a^2 \ge b^2 \ge c^2$ gives $a \ge b \ge c$ for positive numbers, so the only way $(a^2, b^2, c^2)$ and $(b, c, a)$ can be similarly ordered is when $a=b=c$.  $$ $$ Of course if instead of rearrangement we had appealed to three AM-GMs of form $\frac23a^3+\frac13b^3 \ge a^2b$, this may have been easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

A different method. Define:

$$f(a,b)= 1 + a^3 + b^3 - (a + a^2 b + b^2)$$
Show by solving $f'_a = f'_b=0$ that the minimum of $f$ is at $a=b=1$, and that $f(1,1)=0$, proving there is a single solution, $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If the equation $f(a,b,c)=0$ is symmetrical in the sense that $f(a,b,c)=f(\overline{a,b,c})$ where  $\overline{a,b,c}$ represents any permutation of $\{a,b,c\}$ then if it has an extreme point it must be $a=b=c$.

Proof is very simple. Take that it has an extreme point for $a_{0}>b_{0}>c_{0}$. Then by permutation it would have more extreme points where $b_{0}>a_{0}>c_{0}$ or $a_{0}>c_{0}>b_{0}$. Because of this it must be only $a_{0}=b_{0}=c_{0}$.
It remains to prove that the extreme exists and that it is a minimum in this particular case.

For any $a=b=c$ we have $f(a,b,c)=a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}-a^{2}b-b^{2}c-c^{2}a=0$.

Let us have a point $a_{1} \geq b_{1} \geq c_{1} \geq 0$ where it is not 
$a_{1} = b_{1} = c_{1}$

It would be $(a_{1}^{3}-a_{1}^{2}b_{1})+(b_{1}^{3}-b_{1}^{2}c_{1})+(c_{1}^{3}-c_{1}^{2}a_{1})>0$ because each $a_{1}^{3}-a_{1}^{2}b_{1} \geq 0,b_{1}^{3}-b_{1}^{2}c_{1} \geq 0, c_{1}^{3}-c_{1}^{2}a_{1} \geq 0$ but at least one is different from $0$.

So $0$ is a minimum. The solution to the above equation follows.